# Connect Azure API management to my VPN

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-virtual-network, azure-api-management, azure-vpn

I can connect to backend in the Vnet using

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet

However, I could not find how to connect to the backend which resides in VPN.

Can I do as follow

1. Create Vnet
2. Connect Vnet to my VPN using IPsec VPN Tunnel

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways#site-to-site-and-multi-site-ipsecike-vpn-tunnel

3. Connect APIm to subnet ip address (My assumption is this will relay the request to my backend which resides in my VPN)

Answer (score 0):

Once APIM and backend joined same VNET (and there are no security rules preventing that) backend should be directly reachable from APIM service, so settings backend service url for any API with backend hostname or ip address shiould be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to connect my APIM with another service (in my case a container service)

1. create a new vnet with a small subnet and connect it with the APIM
2. peer your APIM vnet with the other vnet where you backend serive is located.
3. peer it also in the other direction with "Allow forward traffic"

What kind of backend are you using?